# Array Partitioning

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a set of object numbered from 1 to n and there is only one instance of each object.Now say, I have received k request, each request is to get some set of object.
So how I should process these requests so that we can process maximum number of request. we have prior knowledge of all the request.

---

Ex: say we have 10 apple numbered from 1 to 10 and three requests:

```
request 1: {2,6}

request 2: {1,2,3,4,5}

request 3: {6,7,8,9,10}
```

so here if we process request 1 then we can full-fill only 1 request but if we process 2 and 3 we can full-fill  2 request.
Please suggest a optimized Algo.

Comment: ... How many *apple* and *requests* are expected? How much time can you spend? What is the desired time complexity? ... Will you accept a randomized algorithm? ... Is approximate algorithm acceptable? ... If you already have an possibly non-optimal solution, would you share it? ...

Comment: Do you want to maximise the number of covered objects in all fulfilled requests or the number of requests that you can fulfill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is called [maximum set packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing): given a set (your array) an a set of subsets (your requests), find the maximum number of subsets (requests) that do not have an element in common (are pairwise disjoint).

As shown in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing#Integer_linear_program_formulation), the problem can be formulated as an integer linear program, which can be solved by a standard solver. Since those are highly optimized, that is as optimal as you can probably get. Like many packing problems, the problem is NP-hard, so you cannot do much better than brute-force if you try to implement this yourself.

Comment: @mok what kind of differences do you see? If you consider the set of array indices, the array becomes irrelevant, right?